# Does go-pg support regex updates?

Tags: go-pg

[go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg) is a Golang library for PostgreSQL. In SQL one could update an entire column by applying a regular expression, e.g.:

```
update <some-column> set x = regexp_replace(x,'^.*\/[0-9]+(.*)$', '\1hello');
```

**Problem**

According the README, one could perform [a bulk update](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10#example-DB.Model-BulkUpdate). However, no information regarding regular expression were neither found in the issue tracker, nor in the documentation.

**Question**

Does this library support `regexp_replace` updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not support it as an ORM, but it supports [plain SQL](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10#DB.Exec). I personally do not like to run it as such, but there seems to be no other choice when this library is used at the moment. One benefit is that the statement will be run in the flow of the go app. For example, once the file paths have been changed on disk, the database could be updated in a controlled way.